# Looking for a PHP template Parser with nesting

Tags: php, regex, parsing, templates

I am looking for a PHP parser that can do this.

```
{tag} Replace the tag with text coming from a function

{tag(params)} It must support params

{tag({tag(params)},{tag(params)})} It must support nesting

{tag()?

else

} It must support Tests

{$tag=value} It must support varriables
```

Does anyone know of a parser that can do this?

Or maybe you know how I can create one. I have tried to do this with preg, but it seems impossible to create nesting.

Smarty seems to be a bit to big, and I don't know if you can disable all the extra functionality it has. I only need the functionality that I have listed above.

In smarty you're able to write PHP code and I don't like that. {php} {/php}
So if I'am going to use that I need to be able to turn it of.

I'm going to use it with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To incorporate nesting in your regular expressions you have to use recursive patterns (?R). This matches whole pattern.

To find outermost {}-s in text (possibly with some other {} inside of them) you should use expression like this:

`/{([^{}]*(?R))*[^{}]+}/`

You can read about (?R) here: http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php

There is a construct `{((?>[^{}]+)|(?R))*}` suggested there. Maybe more efficient than the one I built.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go with Smarty3. Why reinvent the wheel when someone already did years of development, testing and optimization for you?

In Smarty3 `{php}` tag is disabled by default. It also supports [security policies](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/variable.security.settings.php) where you can disable php function calls and such if you are letting users modify your templates.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter did this very well before introducing it's built-in templating. CodeIgniter view templates used to be written simply in PHP and thus you were free to use any PHP features you wish: call structures, function calls and more.

I recommend you simply use the **[View](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)** instead of the [Template Parser](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html).